# Python crashes when I access my function with wxPython

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython, python-2.6

So, I have two pieces of code. The first is the GUI class:

```
'''
Created on Mar 6, 2013

@author: Zach
'''
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Sep  8 2010)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import wx
import wx.grid
from Books import *
###########################################################################
## Class MyFrame1
###########################################################################

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 734,344 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        bSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.patrons_table = wx.grid.Grid( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )

        # Grid
        self.patrons_table.CreateGrid( 0, 7 )
        self.patrons_table.EnableEditing( True )
        self.patrons_table.EnableGridLines( True )
        self.patrons_table.SetGridLineColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_APPWORKSPACE ) )
        self.patrons_table.EnableDragGridSize( True )
        self.patrons_table.SetMargins( 0, 0 )

        # Columns
        self.patrons_table.SetColSize( 0, 100 )
        self.patrons_table.SetColSize( 1, 100 )
        self.patrons_table.SetColSize( 2, 100 )
        self.patrons_table.SetColSize( 3, 100 )
        self.patrons_table.SetColSize( 4, 100 )
        self.patrons_table.SetColSize( 5, 100 )
        self.patrons_table.SetColSize( 6, 100 )
        self.patrons_table.EnableDragColMove( True )
        self.patrons_table.EnableDragColSize( True )
        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelSize( 40 )
        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelValue( 0, "ID" )
        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelValue( 1, "Name" )
        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelValue( 2, "Address" )
        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelValue( 3, "Phone" )
        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelValue( 4, "Email" )
        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelValue( 5, "Fees/Day")
        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelValue( 6, "Fees Owed" )

        self.patrons_table.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )

        # Rows
        self.patrons_table.AutoSizeRows()
        self.patrons_table.EnableDragRowSize( True )
        self.patrons_table.SetRowLabelSize( 80 )
        self.patrons_table.SetRowLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )

        # Label Appearance

        # Cell Defaults
        self.patrons_table.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_LEFT, wx.ALIGN_TOP )
        self.patrons_table.SetToolTipString( u"Table of patrons in the library" )

        bSizer2.Add( self.patrons_table, 7, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM, 5 )

        bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer6.Add( self.m_panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_button1 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_button1.SetToolTipString( u"Adds a patron" )

        bSizer6.Add( self.m_button1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_button2 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Remove", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_button2.SetToolTipString( u"Removes the selected patron" )

        bSizer6.Add( self.m_button2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_button3 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Update", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_button3.SetToolTipString( u"Updates the database" )

        bSizer6.Add( self.m_button3, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        bSizer2.Add( bSizer6, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        bSizer1.Add( bSizer2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        bSizer5 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.m_searchCtrl2 = wx.SearchCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 715,-1 ), 0 )
        self.m_searchCtrl2.ShowSearchButton( True )
        self.m_searchCtrl2.ShowCancelButton( False )
        bSizer5.Add( self.m_searchCtrl2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        bSizer1.Add( bSizer5, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.patrons_table.Bind( wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE, self.onGridChange )
        self.patrons_table.Bind( wx.grid.EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, self.onLeftClick )
        self.m_button1.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addpatron )
        self.m_button2.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.removepatron )
        self.m_button3.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.updatepatronsDatabase )
        self.m_searchCtrl2.Bind( wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_SEARCH_BTN, self.searchpatrons )
        self.m_searchCtrl2.Bind( wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.searchpatrons )


        #Import the Database into the table
        self.lib = Library()
        self.db = Database()
        for i in self.db.getPatrons():
            print "hello"
            self.lib.addPatron(Patron(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4]))
        self.lib.resetHistory()


        for i in self.lib.patrons:
            self.patrons_table.InsertRows()
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,0,str(i["title"]))
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,1,str(i["author"]))
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,2,str(i["patron_id"]))
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,3,str(i["location"]))
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,4,str(i["publisher"]))
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,5,str(i["genre"]))
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,6,str(i["copy_right"]))
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,7,str(i["subject"]))
            self.patrons_table.SetCellValue(0,8,str(i["is_checked_out"]))
    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class

#EVENTS
    def onGridChange( self, event ):# Called if one of the cell values was changed
        updated_patron = Patron(self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),0),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),1),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),2),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),3),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),4),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),5),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),6),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),7),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),8),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),9),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),10))
        self.lib.editPatron(self.selected_patron, updated_patron)
    def onLeftClick( self, event ): #Turns the selected row into a patron
        self.selected_patron = Patron(self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),0),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),1),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),2),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),3),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),4),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),5),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),6),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),7),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),8),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),9),
                             self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow(),10))
        self.row = self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorRow()
        self.column = self.patrons_table.GetGridCursorCol()
        event.Skip()
    def addpatron( self, event ):# adds a patron to the library and the table
        self.patrons_table.InsertRows()
        self.lib.addpatron(Patron())
        event.Skip()
    def removepatron( self, event ): #removes a patron from the table and the library
        self.lib.removepatron(self.selected_patron)
        self.patrons_table.DeleteRows()
        print self.lib.patrons
        event.Skip()
    def updatepatronsDatabase( self, event ): #syncs the database with the library
        self.db.mergeWithLibrary(self.lib)

    def searchpatrons( self, event ):
        value =  self.m_searchCtrl2.GetValue()
        i=0
        while self.patrons_table.GetNumberRows()-1 >i:
            if self.patrons_table.GetCellValue(i,2) == value:
                self.patrons_table.SetGridCursor(i,2)
                self.patrons_table.SelectRow(i)
                self.patrons_table.Scroll(i,i)
                break
            i = i+1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame1(None)
    frame.Show()
    frame.Maximize()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And the second part of the code is the engine behind the GUI class:

```
'''
Created on Mar 2, 2013

@author: Braden

This is a test file to try to make the GUI easier to program
It worked!
'''

import sqlite3 as sq
class Book(object):
    r"""
    This class defines what a book is. All books in the library are book objects
    """
    def __init__(self, title = "n", author = "n", book_id = "n", location = "n", publisher = "n", genre = "n", copy_right = "n", subject = "n", is_checked_out = "n", price = "n", fee_increment = "n"):
        r"""
        This function sets the basic attributes of each book
        """
        self.attributes = {"title":title,
                          "author":author,
                          "book_id":book_id,
                          "location":location,
                          "publisher":publisher,
                          "genre":genre,
                          "copy_right":copy_right,
                          "subject": subject,
                          "is_checked_out":is_checked_out,
                          "price": price,
                          "fee_increment":fee_increment
                          }
    def __str__(self):
        r"""
        This returns a string representation of the book. This is what makes " print book" possible.
        """
        return str(self.attributes)
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        r"""
        This returns an attribute in the book. It makes "book['title']" work.
        """
        return self.attributes[key]
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        r"""
        This sets an attribute to a different value. It makes "book['title'] = 'My New Title' " Possilble ...I think.
        """
        self.attributes[key] = value
    def __cmp__(self,book):
        if self.attributes == book.attributes:
            return True
        else:
            return False      
class Patron(object):
    r"""
    This is the Patron class. It is almost identical to the Book class just with different attributes.
    """
    def __init__(self, patron_id, name, address, phone, email):
        self.attributes = { "patron_id" : patron_id,
                       "name" : name,
                       "address" : address,
                       "phone" : phone,
                       "email" : email,
                       "fee_balance" : 0.00,
                       "fees_per_day" : 0.00,
                       "books_checked_out" : "",
                       "books_overdue" : ""}
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.attributes)
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.attributes[key]
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        self.attributes[key] = value
class Library(object):
    r"""
    This is the Library Class. It manipulates a database that has been loaded into the RAM. 
    """
    def __init__(self):
        r"""
        All this does is set the default values for the two Loaded Databases and the history.
        """
        self.books = []
        self.patrons= []
        self.history = []
    def addBook(self,book):
        r"""
        This appends a book object to the self.books list. Then it appends the action to the self.history list.
        """
        self.books.append(book)
        self.history.append(("book","add",book))     
    def removeBook(self, Book):
        r"""
        This removes a book object from the self.books list. Then it appends the action to the self.history list
        """
        self.books.remove(Book)
        self.history.append(("book","remove",Book))  
    def editBook(self, old_book, new_book):
        original_id = old_book["book_id"]
        r"""
        This edits a book object in the self.books list. Then it appends the action to the self.history list.
        """
        old_book["title"] = new_book["title"]
        old_book["author"] = new_book["author"]
        old_book["book_id"] = new_book["book_id"]
        old_book["location"] = new_book["location"]
        old_book["publisher"] = new_book["publisher"]
        old_book["genre"] = new_book["genre"]
        old_book["copy_right"] = new_book["copy_right"]
        old_book["subject"] = new_book["subject"]
        old_book["is_checked_out"] = new_book["is_checked_out"]
        old_book["price"] = new_book["price"]
        old_book["fee_increment"] = new_book["fee_increment"]
        self.history.append(("book","edit",old_book,original_id))    
    def addPatron(self, patron):
        r"""
        This appends a new Patron object to the self.patrons list. It then appends the action to the self.history list.
        """
        self.patrons.append(patron)
        self.history.append(("patron","add",patron))
        print "bonjour"
        print self.patrons[0]
    def removePatron(self,patron):
        r"""
        This Removes a patron object from the self.patrons list. It then appends the actino to the self.history list.
        """
        self.patrons.remove(patron)
        self.history.append(("patron","remove",patron)) 
    def editPatron(self,patron,attribute,value):
        r"""
        This edits a patron object in the self.patrons list. It then appends the action to the self.history list.
        """
        patron[attribute] = value
        self.history.append(("patron","edit",patron))
    def resetHistory(self):
        r"""
        This resets the self.history list
        """
        self.history=[]
    def getBook(self,book_id):
        r"""
        This finds a book based on its id
        """
        for i in self.books:
            if i["book_id"] == str(book_id):
                return i

    def __str__(self):

        for i in self.books:
            print i
        for i in self.patrons:
            print i         
        return "done"
class Database():
    r"""
    This is the Database Class. It modifies the library.db file.
    """
    def __init__ (self):
        r"""
        This presets the self.database variable and the self.cursor variable
        """
        self.database = sq.connect('library.db')
        self.cursor = self.database.cursor()
    def mergeWithLibrary(self,library):
        r"""
        This is my personal favorite. It updates the library.db file based off of the changes the Library object.

        """
        for i in library.history:
            print i
            if i[0] == "book":
                if i[1] == "add":
                    self.addBook(i[2])
                elif i[1] == "remove":
                    self.deleteBook(i[2])
                elif i[1] == "edit":
                    self.editBook(i[2],i[3])
            elif i[0] == "patron":
                if i[1] == "add":
                    self.addPatron(i[2])
                elif i[1] == "remove":
                    self.deletePatron(i[2])
                elif i[2] == "edit":
                    self.editPatron(i[2])
        library.resetHistory()
    def getBooks(self):
        r"""
        This returns all of the books in the library.db database
        """
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
    def getPatrons(self):
        r"""
        This returns all of the Patrons in the library.db database
        """
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM patrons")
        print self.cursor.fetchall()
        print "called"
        return [(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)]
    def editBook(self,Book,id):
        r"""
        This updates a Book
        """
        self.cursor.execute("UPDATE books SET title = '"+Book["title"]+"', author = '"+Book["author"]+"', book_id= '"+Book["book_id"]+"', location = '"+Book["location"]+"', publisher = '"+Book["publisher"]+"', genre = '"+Book["genre"]+"', copy_right = '"+Book["copy_right"]+"', subject = '"+Book["subject"]+"', is_checked_out = '"+Book["is_checked_out"]+"', price = '"+Book["price"]+"', fee_increment = '"+Book["fee_increment"]+"' WHERE book_id = '"+id+"'")

        self.database.commit()
        print Book["fee_increment"]
    def editPatron(self,Patron):
        r"""
        This edits a Patron
        """
        self.cursor.execute("UPDATE patrons SET name= '"+Patron["name"]+"', address = '"+Patron["address"]+"', phone = '"+str(Patron["phone"])+"', email = '"+Patron["email"]+"', fee_balance = '"+str(Patron["fee_balance"])+"', fees_per_day = '"+str(Patron["fees_per_day"])+"', books_checked_out = '"+Patron["books_checked_out"]+"', books_overdue = '" +Patron["books_overdue"]+"' WHERE id ="+str(Patron["patron_id"]))
        self.database.commit()
    def deleteBook(self,Book):
        r"""
        This deletes a book
        """
        self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM books WHERE book_id = "+"'"+Book["book_id"]+"'")
        self.database.commit()
    def deletePatron(self,Patron):
        r"""
        """
        self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM patrons WHERE id = "+"'"+str(Patron["patron_id"])+"'")
        self.database.commit()
    def addBook(self,Book):
        r"""
        This adds a book
        """
        data = [        
        Book["title"],
        Book["author"],
        Book["book_id"],
        Book["location"],
        Book["publisher"],
        Book["genre"],
        Book["copy_right"],
        Book["subject"],
        Book["is_checked_out"],
        Book["price"],
        Book["fee_increment"]
        ]
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO books VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", data)
        self.database.commit()
    def addPatron(self,Patron):
        r"""
        This adds a Patron
        """
        data = [Patron["patron_id"],
        Patron["name"],
        Patron["address"],
        Patron["phone"],
        Patron["email"],
        Patron["fee_balance"],
        Patron["fees_per_day"], 
        Patron["books_checked_out"], 
        Patron["books_overdue"]]
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO patrons VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",data)
        self.database.commit()
```

Every time I run my code, all my little `print` statement flags pop up in the console, but the window doesn't open and then python crashes. Commenting out the `for` statement where I import my database into the table lets the program run, but any calls to `self.lib.addPatron` will crash the program again. I see no problems with that function, am I just stupid?

Comment: You're probably not stupid, but you'll get more help here if you can pare down your code to a simpler example.  Doing so might you solve your problem too!

Comment: I knew that this was probably too long, but I'm not advanced enough to know for 100% sure how to pare down the code so that the solution can be found. Thanks for your input, though! It'll help in the future.

Comment: Oh! And I'm using Python 2.6, if that makes any difference to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you'd given us the traceback you were getting. When I run this code, I get the following:

```
  sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: patrons
  File "c:\Users\mdriscoll\Desktop\brk.py", line 191, in <module>
    frame = MyFrame1(None)
  File "c:\Users\mdriscoll\Desktop\brk.py", line 115, in __init__
    for i in self.db.getPatrons():
  File "c:\Users\mdriscoll\Desktop\Books.py", line 184, in getPatrons
    self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM patrons")
```

Since you state that you too are getting an issue on "self.lib.addPatron", then that means that this is likely the same issue. As the traceback indicates, the table does not exist. You need to create the table (even if they're empty) BEFORE you can add anything to do them. This article might help you get started: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/python-a-simple-step-by-step-sqlite-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

When debugging WXpython programs that crash before giving you any useful output, you can save the errors to a logfile by specifying a redirect when you start the app. So changing the line that starts the app to:

```
app = wx.pySimpleApp(redirect=True,  filename="logfile.txt")
```

will save your errors to a logfile in the same folder as your script, and then you will have a better idea of what's going on.